# How to remove files having the same name of subfolders in a different folder?

Tags: bash, directory, filenames

I have 10k files into a folder (folder_A). A second folder (folder_B) contains 100k subfolders.
Some of the subfolders have the same name of files into folder A.
Here is an example:

```
ls ./folder_A
aaa.txt bbb.txt ccc.txt
ls ./folder_B
aaa/ bbb/ ddd/ xxx/
```

I need to remove files from folder_A, when a subfolder with the same name exist in folder_B, so that folder_A will contains only files which name is not present in folder_B, like this:

```
ls folder_A
ccc.txt
```

Is there a way to do this in bash?
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? How did it fail?

Comment: @choroba actually I am new to bash and terminal in general, and I am still trying to learn. By reading on the web, maybe I could try to use "find", to generate a list of the files which I have to delete, but I have no idea which parameter to use. Any suggestion would be very appreciated

Comment: Do you only want to check and delete files with the `.txt` suffix?

Comment: @Freddy yes! Only files with .txt suffix which names are present in subfolders names

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the files in folder_A and for each one check whether the corresponding directory exists in folder_B. Parameter expansion can help you remove the .txt extension and the path.

```bsh
for f in folder_A/*.txt ; do
    d=${f%.txt}           # Remove .txt at the end.
    d=folder_B/${d##*/}   # Remove everything before the last /.
    if [[ -d $d ]] ; then
        rm "$f"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks @choroba! I will try this!